# CMake: How to let sub directory install before parent build

Tags: cmake

The Top project A have two add_subdirectory(B),add_subdirectory(C).
and A will include the header file generated by B, so in B, the INSTALL will copy the files to dist. 
The question is:
    Always when building A, the INSTALL of B and C only be executed after B,C,A building finished, thus for the first time, Build of A always failed as header files are not existed.

**The subdir: eventloop**

```
project(eventloop)

aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}  src_list)
message("event ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ")
add_library(eventloop ${src_list})

set_target_properties(eventloop PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER 
"IDeferredMethodRunner.hpp;IFdEventHandler.hpp;IEventLoop.hpp;ITimerEventHandler.hpp;TEventLoop.hpp;TEventPump.hpp;TEventItem.hpp;TEventFd.hpp")
INSTALL(TARGETS eventloop 
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION $ENV{ECARX_PROJECT_ROOT_PATH}/dist/lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION $ENV{ECARX_PROJECT_ROOT_PATH}/dist/lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION  $ENV{ECARX_PROJECT_ROOT_PATH}/dist/include/eventloop
        )

add_custom_command(
    TARGET eventloop
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target install
    )
```

**The Top dir: vehicleman**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
project(vehicleman)



add_subdirectory(../../common/cpp/eventloop   event)
add_subdirectory(../../common/cpp/socket   socket)


aux_source_directory(. src_list)
add_executable(vehicleman ${src_list} )
target_include_directories(vehicleman PUBLIC $ENV{ECARX_PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(vehicleman pthread eventloop socket)
##add_dependencies(vehicleman $ENV{ECARX_PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR})
#[[find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

include(GoogleTest)

set(unittest_srcs unittests/main.cpp TProcess.cpp)

add_executable(tests ${unittest_srcs})

add_executable(dumy_bin unittests/dumy_bin.cpp)


target_include_directories(tests PUBLIC ./)
target_link_libraries(tests gtest gtest_main pthread eventloop)
enable_testing()
##gtest_add_tests(TARGET tests TEST_PREFIX old:)
##gtest_discover_tests(tests TEST_PREFIX new:)
add_test(NAME test COMMAND tests)
]]
```

Generally speaking, when building vehicleman, I want cmake

1. Build eventloop
2. Install eventloop
3. Build vehicleman

Comment: If a project (`eventloop` in your case) is included into other project via `add_subdirectory`, you cannot *install* a subproject separately. `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target install` installs the *whole project*, not just eventloop. If you want to mix build and installing of subproject with build and installing of main project, use [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) for include the subproject into the main one, not a `add_subdirectory`.